# User guide for Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am trying to develop an app using Xamarin.
Do you know if there is a user guide available or online courses on how to learn how to use it? (the Xamarin website doen't offer so much informations).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here are some paid online courses :

[Beginning Mobile Development with Xamarin - Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/beginning-mobile-development-xamarin)

[Xamarin Essential Training - Lynda](https://www.lynda.com/Development-Tools-tutorials/Xamarin-Essential-Training/449034-2.html)

[Learn Xamarin by Creating Real World Cross-Platform Apps - Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/learn-xamarin-by-creating-real-cross-platform-apps/?altsc=428120)

Youtube Playlist for Xamarin Android :

[Xamarin Android tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l)

There are more great resources on the internet if you search more..